# Implementing search criteria using JSP and SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to implement a search functionality using JSP and SQL Server. I am required to search using keywords such a phone number. But my lecturer wants me to implement the search functionality a bit differently.

Let's say - I have a phone number in the database `123456` and I key in the number in the search box `123`. The procedure should be able to retrieve all the records with the phone number that starts with `123`.

I tried the following so far but I have to enter the full number for the results to be retrieved. How can I change my procedure so that it works the way my lecturer wants?

```
USE [test]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[add_data]    Script Date: 15-11-2016 10:14:51 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE Procedure [dbo].[select_data]
(
@thePhoneNumber VARCHAR(200),
@theName     VARCHAR(200) OUT

)
As
Begin
     SELECT @theName= Name  FROM real WHERE PhoneNumber=@thePhoneNumber
End
```

Comment: Please mark the answer correct if it helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is the answer you are looking for but for a normal SQL query you should use the `%` sign every time you want to search the rest.

For example in this context you should use:

```
SELECT phonenumber FROM real WHERE phonenumber LIKE '123%'
```

Hope it Helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Like operator will help you in this case.

```
USE [test]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[add_data]    Script Date: 15-11-2016 10:14:51 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE Procedure [dbo].[select_data]
(
@thePhoneNumber VARCHAR(200),
@theName     VARCHAR(200) OUT

)
As
Begin
     SELECT @theName= Name  FROM real WHERE PhoneNumber like '@thePhoneNumber+'%'
End
```

Comment: :- Thank you for your reply. But unfortunately, I get null results as name. What could be the issue?

Comment: @Farheen It should instead of `SELECT @theName= Name  FROM real WHERE PhoneNumber like @thePhoneNumber+'%'`

Comment: @ TT - You are life saver. Thank you tons. Wish I could vote your answer but my reputation point don't allow me. But thank you so much..

Comment: @Farheen I'm sure it was just a typo of the OP. BTW: you're welcome ;-). If you have 10 (or was it 15?) or more reputation, you will be able to upvote as well.